# If a set $X$ contains three different elements $a,b,c$ describe $f:=t(a,b)∘t(b,c)$ and $g:=t(b,c)∘t(a,b)$. Are they equal?

Tags: group-theory

The group of permutations of a set $X$ consists of all functions $f:X\to X$ that are one-to-one and onto. The group operation is the composition of functions. Of special importance are transpositions $t(a,b)$ that switch $a$ and $b$ while keeping all other points fixed. If a set $X$ contains three different elements $a,b,c$ describe $f:=t(a,b)∘t(b,c)$ and $g:=t(b,c)∘t(a,b)$. Are they equal?

Comment: For a small example like this, you can write down a table which describes the action of $f$ and $g$ on $a,b,c$ and just compare them.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $$g(a) = (t(b,c) \circ t(a,b))(a) = (t(b,c))(b) = c.$$  What's $f(a)$?